# chef remote file fails behind proxy

Tags: proxy, chef-infra, cookbook

I am running the following remote file command in on of my chef recipes. I am unable to get it to use the proxy. git commands will use the proxy and so will anything else, but it fails when using `remote file`

```
remote_file "Fetch the latest ca-bundle" do
  source "http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem"
  path "/opt/local/etc/certs/cacert.pem"
  owner "git"
  group "git"
  mode 0755
  action :create
end
```

the error:

`Error connecting to http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem - getaddrinfo: Name or service not known`

I have the following env vars set with my proxy

HTTP_PROXY

HTTPS_PROXY

http_proxy

https_proxy

is there a way to define the proxy in the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the proxy settings in your `client.rb`:

```rb
# HTTP for environment behind firewall
# http://docs.opscode.com/config.html
# solo.rb and client.rb can use the same http_proxy settings
http_proxy "http://proxy.company.com:3128"
http_proxy_user "username"
http_proxy_pass "password"
```